# How can i achieve a viewpager for a certain portion of my screen?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to achieve a horizontal scroll view for a linear layout. I thought of doing this using viewpager but i am not able to figure out how?

[Layout I want to achieve:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRtfg.jpg)

Comment: each page of view pager is a fragment, and you can do any layout you like on a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take 2 FrameLayouts inside your parent linear layout and inside of the frame layout add your view pager. Something like below,

```
 <FrameLayout>
  <ViewPager/>
 </FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout>
  <ViewPager/>
 </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```